# Using a Bin$(k,\theta)$ random sample ($k$ known), determine the posterior distribution for $\theta$ using a Jeffrey's prior.

Tags: binomial-distribution, bayesian, bayes-theorem, log-likelihood

My question here is, am I misinterpreting a binomial random sample? Doing some research on this I'm thinking perhaps I have misunderstood something - however my answer "feels" okay regardless? Although I think I've maybe just used a few tricks that may not make sense to get my answer...

This is my interpretation of the question:

$$\begin{align}
&X_i|\theta \sim Bin(k, \theta), \; i = 1,...,n\;, 0\leq \theta \leq 1 \\\\
\implies f_{\underline{X}}(\underline{X}|\theta) 
&= \prod_{i=1}^n {k \choose x_{i}} \theta^{x_i}(1 - \theta)^{k-x_{i}}\\
&= \theta^{\sum x_i}(1-\theta)^{nk - \sum x_i} \left(\prod_{i=1}^n {k \choose x_{i}}\right)\\
&\propto \theta^{\sum x_i}(1-\theta)^{k - \sum x_i}
\end{align}$$

(Once the data is observed $\prod_{i=1}^n {k \choose x_{i}}$ is just a constant)

So,

$$\begin{align}
\log{f_{\underline{X}}(\underline{X}|\theta)} 
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\log{\theta} + \left(nk - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\log{(1-\theta)} + \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n {k \choose x_{i}}\right)\\
\implies \frac{\partial \log{f_{\underline{X}}(\underline{X}|\theta)}}{\partial \theta} 
&= \frac{1}{\theta}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) - \frac{1}{1-\theta}\left(nk - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \\
\implies \frac{\partial^2 \log{f_{\underline{X}}(\underline{X}|\theta)}}{\partial \theta^2} 
&= -\frac{1}{\theta^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) - \frac{1}{(1-\theta)^2}\left(nk - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \\ \\
\implies I(\theta) 
&= E\left[- \frac{\partial^2 \log{f_{\underline{X}}(\underline{X}|\theta)}}{\partial \theta^2}\right]\\
&= E\left[\frac{1}{\theta^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) + \frac{1}{(1-\theta)^2}\left(nk - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\theta^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n E[x_i|\theta]\right) + \frac{1}{(1-\theta)^2}\left(nk - \sum_{i=1}^n E[x_i|\theta]\right)\\
&= \frac{nk}{\theta} + \frac{nk}{(1-\theta)^2} - \frac{nk\theta}{(1-\theta)^2}\\
&= \frac{nk}{\theta(1-\theta)}
\end{align}$$

Hence, the Jeffrey's prior is

$$
\pi(\theta) \propto \sqrt{\frac{nk}{\theta(1-\theta)}} \propto \sqrt{\frac{k}{\theta(1-\theta)}}
$$

So, using Bayes' Theorem:

$$\begin{align}
\pi(\theta | \underline{X}) 
&\propto \theta^{\sum x_i}(1-\theta)^{k - \sum x_i} \sqrt{\frac{k}{\theta(1-\theta)}}\\
&\propto C\theta^{n\bar{x} - 1/2}(1-\theta)^{k - n\bar{x} - 1/2}
\end{align}$$

Thus, we get a Beta posterior distribution, specifically:

$$
\theta|\underline{X} \sim Beta(n\bar{x} + 1/2, k-n\bar{x} + 1/2)
$$

Comment: Why do you think you're misinterpreting something? Apart from the fact that you could have calculated the Jeffreys (not "Jeffrey's") prior from a single $X_i$ instead of going through the summation and dropping $n$ in the end, it superficially looks OK to me.

Comment: @joriki it is exactly that I am unsure about - I didn't know really why I was dropping the n there, I could just tell I needed to to make it "work". So, is it valid for me to calculate the binomial likelihood and Jeffreys prior for just a single $X$? This part could be nonsense, but - I was getting the feeling that the $n$ is in fact the $k$..? and I could just use $X|\theta \sim Bin(k, \theta)$ from the start which makes everything a lot simpler. I feel like I'm struggling to explain what I mean correctly, apologies if this is nonsense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a binomial or Bernoulli likelihood on the parameter $\theta$, the conjugate prior is Beta distributed.  It is not necessary to normalize the prior to make it a proper density because we only need to retain proportionality: $$f(\theta \mid x) \propto f(x \mid \theta) p(\theta).$$  Any constant with respect to $\theta$ on the right-hand side of the above will not affect the calculation of the posterior.

For example, your Jeffrey's prior you calculated was $$p(\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{k}{\theta(1-\theta)}}$$ which is proportional to a Beta density with prior hyperparameters $\alpha = \beta = 1/2$.  For a likelihood of a **single** binomial observation $$f(x \mid \theta) = \binom{k}{x} \theta^x (1-\theta)^{k-x},$$ this gives us the posterior

$$f(\theta \mid x) \propto \binom{k}{x} \sqrt{k} \theta^{x-1/2} (1-\theta)^{k-x-1/2}.$$

But the factor $\binom{k}{x} \sqrt{k}$ is irrelevant:  what matters is the kernel $\theta^{x-1/2} (1-\theta)^{k-x-1/2}$ which is proportional to a Beta density with posterior hyperparameters $\alpha^* = x + 1/2$, $\beta^* = k-x+1/2$.  Had we instead used  $$p(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}}$$ as our Jeffrey's prior, the result would be the same for the posterior because we ignored the $\sqrt{k}$ factor anyway.  Or we could have even used the proper Beta Jeffrey's prior density
$$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{\theta(1-\theta)}}.$$  It makes no difference.

The above easily generalizes to a likelihood on a sample of $n$ binomial observations:

$$f(\theta \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto \theta^{n \bar x - 1/2}(1-\theta)^{n(k - \bar x) - 1/2}.$$  Note you have an error in your posterior; this is because for a sample of size $n$, the sample total $\sum x_i = n \bar x$ is binomial with parameters $nk$ and $\theta$, so the likelihood is proportional to that for a single observation of a binomial variable with those parameters; i.e., $n\bar x \in \{0, 1, \ldots, nk\}$.